# Understand for-loop in .NET 8.0 C# example

Tags: c#

To program a special CollectionEditor, I looked at the Microsoft example, http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Designer/CompMod/System/ComponentModel/Design/CollectionEditor@cs/1/CollectionEditor@cs. 
There's a for loop that I don't understand.

```
object[] items = createdItems.ToArray(); 
for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++)="" {="" destroyinstance(items[i]);="" }="" createditems.clear();="" if="" (removeditems="" !="null)" removeditems.clear();="" restore="" the="" original="" contents.="" because="" objects="" get="" parented="" during="" createandaddinstance,="" underlying="" collection="" gets="" changed="" add,="" but="" not="" other="" operations.="" all="" consumers="" of="" this="" dialog="" can="" roll="" back="" every="" single="" change,="" will="" at="" least="" additions,="" removals="" and="" reordering.="" see="" asurt="" #85470.="" (originalitems="" &&="" (originalitems.count=""> 0)) { 
// Do some Code
}
```

So far I only knew for loops`for(initializer condition; iterator){}`

What happens at this for-loop?

Many thanks

Ottilie

I want to understand what is going on in this section of the code. Since I implement my own CollectionEditor, the description of the interface does not help me. The task of the method is "Aborts changes made in the editor.", but I would like to understand exactly how it does it. Similar for loops occur elsewhere in the code and I cannot match them with the loop specification. Is there a definition for for-loops anywhere that I could apply here?

Ottilie

Comment: Does that compile?

Comment: This looks more like an error in formatting the code for display as HTML. I highly doubt this is the actual code in the library.

Comment: It means something's stuffed up on that website, either in displaying the file or in importing the source. It's not valid, it's not worth  looking at.

Comment: Use https://referencesource.microsoft.com/ instead when looking at source code.

Comment: It said in the comments from the link `Aborts changes made in the editor.`

Comment: That link is *not* the .NET Framework source code. Someone created a site with a copy of the source code, with broken formatting

Comment: Windows Forms is [open-sourced in Github now](https://github.com/dotnet). The [CollectionEditor.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/master/src/System.Windows.Forms.Design/src/System/ComponentModel/Design/CollectionEditor.cs) file doesn't contain anything like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid code. This is *not* a link to the .NET Source code. It's a site with a copy of the Visual Studio 2005-era code (Whidbey). The site has serious formatting errors and that code is simply garbled.

Windows Forms is open source now, [hosted on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms). The actual [CollectionEditor.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/master/src/System.Windows.Forms.Design/src/System/ComponentModel/Design/CollectionEditor.cs) file is quite clean. The code for [OKButton_Clicked](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/master/src/System.Windows.Forms.Design/src/System/ComponentModel/Design/CollectionEditor.cs#L1374) is quite simple :

```
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!_dirty || !CollectionEditable)
        {
            _dirty = false;
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            return;
        }

        if (_dirty)
        {
            object[] items = new object[_listbox.Items.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                items[i] = ((ListItem)_listbox.Items[i]).Value;
            }

            Items = items;
        }

        if (_removedItems != null && _dirty)
        {
            object[] deadItems = _removedItems.ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < deadItems.Length; i++)
            {
                DestroyInstance(deadItems[i]);
            }
            _removedItems.Clear();
        }

        _createdItems?.Clear();
        _originalItems?.Clear();

        _listbox.Items.Clear();
        _dirty = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
        DisplayError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Panagiotis Kanavos, thank you very much for your help. That was exactly the information I was missing. Ottilie